# Enable/Disable user control using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have an usercontrol which should be disabled/enabled based on a dropdown selection.Please find below the piece of code.

```
  if (name== 'A') {
        $("#uc_panel").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#uc_btnAddCategory").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#uc_ddlCategorySelection").prop("disabled", "disabled");}
  else
  {
    $("#uc_panel").prop("disabled", "");
    $("#uc_btnAddCategory").prop("disabled", "");
    $("#uc_ddlCategorySelection").prop("disabled", "");
  }
```

1st time I select 'A' from the dropdown , usercontrol is disabled. 2nd time I select 'B' and click on BtnAdd, the usercontrol is getting disabled but it should be enabled

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `prop` function, use boolean as values when props are `'disabled'`, `'checked'`, etc. You can check [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2). The way you are using `prop` is same as was used in older versions of jquery with `attr` function

```
if (name == 'A') {
    $("#uc_panel").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#uc_btnAddCategory").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#uc_ddlCategorySelection").prop("disabled", true);
} else {
    $("#uc_panel").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#uc_btnAddCategory").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#uc_ddlCategorySelection").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

So you can shorter it like this:

```
var isA = name == 'A';
$("#uc_panel").prop("disabled", isA);
$("#uc_btnAddCategory").prop("disabled", isA);
$("#uc_ddlCategorySelection").prop("disabled", isA);
```

or:

```
$("#uc_panel, #uc_btnAddCategory, #uc_ddlCategorySelection").prop("disabled", name == 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

This Help You.

> HTML

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="checkField(this.value)">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txt" value="Hello">
```

> Javascript

```
<script>
   function checkField(val)
    {          
      var button = document.getElementById("txt");
      button.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

On Drop Down change it will disable the textbox

Moreover, In order to respond of the change of the selected index, add this [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) event to the dropdown: onchange="disableButton()"